# Has image downscaling improved in Safari 6 and 7? (5 used to be slightly blurred)

Tags: safari

Has image downscaling improved in Safari 6 and 7 (5 used to be slightly blurred)?

I tried to use browserstack but most of them are safari 5...cant see 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it has improved since version 6. Remember safari 5 was released in 2010.

Please make sure to do some google searching before asking simpler questions.